# Trying to use a Model method in View Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I'm working on this project (an Inventory app). I have this model method I am trying to use in my View. I'm trying to call it in my view.

But I'm always getting an error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_quantities_sold'

Here is my model:

```
generate_ref_no = str(uuid.uuid1())

class Transaction(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business_Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    productSold = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quanties_of_product_sold = models.IntegerField()
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_method = models.CharField(choices=PAYMENT_METHOD, max_length=50)
    reference_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False, default=generate_ref_no)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer} '


    def get_quantities_sold(self,quantities_sold):
        return print(quantities_sold)
```

My view:

```
class TransactionView(generics.GenericAPIView):
  def post(self,request, business=None):
      serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=request.data)
      if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
              getTransaction = Transaction.objects.filter(reference_num=serializer.data['reference_num'])
              getTransaction_serializer = TransactionSerializer(getTransaction, many=True)
              getTransaction.get_quantities_sold(serializer.data['quanties_of_product_sold '])
              return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I'm trying to call the 'get_quantities_sold' method from the Transaction model in my transaction view but I'm an error: QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_quantities_sold'

Comment: `getTransaction` is a `QuerySet` and thus a *collection* of items, not a single item, hence `getTransaction.get_quantities_sold` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTransaction` is in your method is a `QuerySet` and thus a *collection* of items, not a single item, hence `getTransaction.get_quantities_sold` makes no sense. You can retrieve a single `Transaction` object by using [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) over [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

```
getTransaction = Transaction.objects.get(
    reference_num=serializer.data['reference_num']
)
```

It might also be worth to guarantee uniqueness for the `reference_num` with:

```
reference_num = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    editable=False,
    default=generate_ref_no,
    unique=True
)
```